# Yammer for SharePoint App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, yammer

I followed the instructions in this document, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659289(v=office.15).aspx,  for getting yammer integrated with SharePoint on-premise.  However, this application is not available in the Office Store anymore.

Anyone have any idea if there is a new application, if this one isn't supported anymore or any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking at showing Yammer feed in your SharePoint site, you can embed the feed using the js code. Get the appropriate code for the required feed using the below link

https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure

And, if you want to show Other sections like Announcements, Recent Activities, Search for People etc., you can use my App from the SharePoint App Store - https://store.office.com/yammer-parts-WA104377502.aspx?assetid=WA104377502

Regards,
Ram.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We are going to use the widget instead.